# How to escape single quote (') in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

`<h1 th:text="${'What\'s up?'}"></h1>`

I want this to output

`<h1>What's up?</h1>`

But I get an `TemplateInputException`. I have tried with HTML entity but it fails the same.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Double single quote.  Like this:

```
<h1 th:text="${'What''s up?'}" />
```

Comment: You are correct. Could you please explain why it works like that?

Comment: Not really sure why they chose that way, but it's not an uncommon strategy (at the very least, it's the same in SQL).

Answer (score 10):

To escape a single quote you just escape it with a `\'`

```
<p th:text="'What\'s up?'"></p>
<p th:text="${myVar} + 'What\'s up?'"></p>
```

Comment: worked in a th:attr="data-original-title=#{message.key}" + 'what\'s up' " context. The accepted answer didn't work in that case: th:attr="data-original-title=#{message.key}" + 'what''s up' " resulted in a org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence.

Answer (score 3):

maybe use htm ascii code : `&#39;`

```
<h1 th:text="${'What&#39;s up&#63;'}"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want transfer code such as onclick="showName('John')" to thymeleaf expression,
use th:onclick=(${'showName'(\''+name+'\''}) that will get error：EL1065E: Unexpected escape character. And then,use double sigle quote to fix：

```html
is this right?
<div th:onclick="${'showName('''+name+''''}"></div>
```

do test,WTF! double single quote is escaped to '&#39';。after some research，i found the corret way is：

```html
correct now：
<div th:onclick="'showName(\''+${name}+'\''"></div>
```

you should keep ${name} as whole,as an atomic,don't use '+' operation in it.

i think only th:onclick just like that,th:text can use add operation in it.

My English is funny,but i think you can understand.