# getting Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: error in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, parse-error

I am trying to replace the single quote (') character in my thymeleaf template. As our encoding is escaping it to `&#39;` and the client is expecting it to be `&apos;`

To implement a quick fix, I am planning to replace all the occurrences of the single quote (') character in the payload with a space. However, doing so, I am getting the following error:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:

The replace expression I have used:

```
<th:block th:with="Description=${op.jpText('$.short_description')}">
  <u_short_description  th:text="${#strings.replace(Description,''',' ')}"></u_short_description>
</th:block>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quote (') in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121788/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<th:block th:with="Description=${op.jpText('$.short_description')}">
  <u_short_description th:text="${#strings.replace(Description,'''',' ')}" />
</th:block>
```

You aren't correctly escaping the single quote in your `replace`.