# What is the correct syntax for location.href

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been trying to figure out how to pass a url to a spring controller method through a button via th:onclick. I've tried many different variations of these and can not figure out how many ' I am supposed to have or if I am escaping things correctly. Can someone please explain why this isn't working/what the correct way to use location.href is?

currently this is the error: Could not parse as expression: "'window.location.href=\'/removeContact''"

thank you!!

```html
 <button type="button" th:onclick="'window.location.href=\'/removeContact''" name="removeContact" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger trashContact"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use an anchor?

Comment: You're wrapping the statement in both " and '. Drop the '. Just use `th:onclick="window.location.href='/removeContact'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${..} is variable expressions in Thymeleaf and is also spel.

So use [two single quotes in spel expression for escape single quote.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43122327/1615988)

```
th:onclick="'window.location.href=${'''/removeContact'''}'"
```

And use back slash and single quote in [Thymeleaf standard expression text literal](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literals).

```
th:onclick="'window.location.href=\'/removeContact\''"
```

Comment: The second option you listed @gilchris is the only one that worked for me. Thank you!